# Performance and range of wifi usb adapter differs

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter

I have wondered for a long time why the range and performance of my Wi-Fi usb adapter with two different Windows 10 devices differs greatly. The driver is up to date on both devices, I tried different slots. I am using a 
**Realtek RTL8188EU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter**.

Because the built in Wi-Fi of the Acer is not working anymore the adapter is necessary.

The performance on my *Packard bell EasyNote LS* is ten times higher than on my *Acer Aspire V*.

Technical Details:

- Packard bell:

  - Wifi: Realtek RTL8192SE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
  - Bluetooth: Not included

---

- Acer Apire:

  - Wifi: Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter (not working)
  - Bluetooth: Qualcomm Atheros Communications (switched off)

I am aware that the adapter is not the best of its kind, but the different performances seem weird. Maybe someone already knows this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I speculate a number of things including RFI (radio interference) from the PC/laptop - which is generated by  the CPU and other components.  As (I assume from online ones i've seen) its a pretty smll device with no external aerial it is probably more sensitive to noise then other devices.

Comment: Please edit your Question to include the technical details of the built-in Wi-Fi and Bluetooth of both of your laptops, and why you're trying to use this external adapter instead of the built-in stuff, and whether you've fully powered off the built-in Wi-Fi and Bluetooth of both laptops. Also, have you tried putting your USB Wi-Fi dongle at the end of a USB extender cable (or external USB hub at the end of a 1-2m cable) in order to get it away from the internal RF noise of your laptops?

Comment: Thank you davidgo and Spiff, I included a few technical details @spiff: I will try an extender cable.